# How do I print with an Epson SC P800 onto real Hahnemuehle watercolour paper (un-primed for inkjet)?

Tags: printing, paper, painting

I want to print onto actual watercolour paper with my Epson SC P800, after which I will paint with watercolour paints.

I have tried the Hannemühle 308 gsm inkjet photorag paper but this is primed with a substance to help take the inkjet inks and the watercolour paint doesn't respond in the same way as normal paper. Does anyone have any advice on how not to screw up my printer when using real watercolour paper? How do I make sure that I get the right gap between the nozzles and the paper? And are there any ICC profiles out there for this combination? I'm presuming that I just plug in 'velvet fine art paper' for the printer? General advice welcomed... thanks.

Comment: I think this might do better on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why not contact Hannemühle directly and ask the question. Maybe they can give you the closest profile to choose.

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to find profiles and it will be most likely hard to make your own - since the paper has completely different properties than regular inkjet papers, you will need to experiment with amount of ink. Settings for ordinary office paper is probably a good start.

If you are unsure about the platen gap setting, set the largest.